# Does this sequence of functions converges uniformly?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

¿Converges uniformly? $$f_n (x)= n^3 x^n (1-x)^4$$ for $$ x\in\mathcal [0,1]$$

I have this, it's clear that $$\lim_{x\to \infty}f_n (x)= n^3 x^n (1-x)^4 =0$$
Then 
$$ |f(x)-f_n (x)|=|f_n (x)| $$
So, note that
$$n^3 x^n (1-x)^4 \leq n^3 x^n \leq n^3 < \epsilon $$ for all  $$ x\in\mathcal [0,1]$$
Thus i took 
$$ \frac {1 }{\sqrt[3]{\epsilon}}<\frac{1}{n},\frac {1 }{\sqrt[3]{\epsilon}}+1<\frac{1}{n}+1= \frac {n+1}{n}<n+1$$
Finally $$f_n(x)$$ converges uniformly for $$N=\frac {1 }{\sqrt[3]{\epsilon}}+1$$ for all $$N\leq n$$
I'm not sure if the epsilon is correct?

Comment: Your reasoning is not correct. In particular, the upper bound $n^3$ is totally useless in order to prove uniform convergence (because it diverges as $n\to \infty$). See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $f_n(x)\geq 0$ in $[0,1]$ and $f_n \in C^\infty(]0,1[) \cap C([0,1])$, therefore you can use the $M$-test.

In order to find $M_n=\max |f_n - f| = \max f_n$, you can differentiate to find:

$$f_n^\prime (x) = n^3 \Big[ n x^{n-1}(1-x)^4 - 4x^n (1-x)^3\Big] = n^3 x^{n-1}(1-x)^3 \Big[n-(n + 4)x\Big] \geq 0\quad \text{iff}\quad 0< x\leq \frac{n}{n+4}$$

therefore in $\frac{n}{n+4}$ the function $f_n$ takes its maximum, which is:

$$M_n = f_n \left( \frac{n}{n+4}\right) = n^3 \left( \frac{n}{n+4}\right)^n \left( 1 - \frac{n}{n+4}\right)^4 = \frac{4^4n^3}{(n+4)^4} \left( 1 - \frac{4}{n+4}\right)^n\; .$$

Since $M_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, your sequence converge uniformly on $[0,1]$. ;-)

Comment: Hi, why did you take $\frac{n}{n+4}$ as the upper bound of the inequality? Thanks.